# Findbugs says "HTTP parameter directly written to HTTP header"

Tags: java, http, findbugs

When i execute these lines

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename='" + fileName + "'");
```

where fileName is a String.

There is another duplicate question which talks about getting headers and checking whether it is null. But my problem is about setting headers.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above solution is about getting header and checking whether it is null or not, but my problem is on setting headers

Comment: Do you know what the findbug warning means? If not better study the findbug documentation to find out and then check the linked solution again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindBugs complains about your code allowing the value of a response header to contain something obtained from the request, which could be used to cause the response to become a security problem (google for "http response smuggling").

Anyway, on top of that, there are at least two more problems in the code:

- the quoting character in this header field is the double quote
- even when using quoting, you might still create invalid header fields, such as when the filename itself contains double quotes, or when it contains non-ASCII characters

See RFC 6266 for more details.